# Does google app script simultaneous executions quota apply for the script in question or for each users?

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

Google app script 'Simultaneous executions'(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas) quota is limited to 30, but I am wondering if this quota is for each user or for each script project? I couldn't find any clarification for on the documentation. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: For the Apps Script project, ***unless*** the Apps Script project is used as an add-on.  If it's an add-on, then the add-on runs under the authority of the account that installed the add-on, and uses the quota of the account that installed the add-on.  And that's the same for a library also.  If your script is a Web App and your hoping that if you had 1000 users all using your Web App at the same time, isn't going to break your Web App, then you'll be disappointed.

Comment: To add to @Alan's web app comment, this won't be problem, if the web app is deployed as user accessing.

Comment: Okay thank you all, it's deployed as API executable so the limit is for the project then.