# 'Exception: Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets' - Is it because I am opening spreadsheets in a loop?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, simultaneous, simultaneous-calls

I have been getting the error:

> Exception: Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets

I have looked on the [quota page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages) and it doesn't say anything about opening spreadsheets. I am assuming a simultaneous invocation is where something happens at the same time as something else, but I would assume my script, which is only run from a single trigger, would work through each process one by one and, therefore, should not have anything happening simultaneously. Am I completely mistaken? I looked at [Does google app script simultaneous executions quota apply for the script in question or for each users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61060108/does-google-app-script-simultaneous-executions-quota-apply-for-the-script-in-que) but I still don't know what it is about.

I have tried running the script manually and it seems to work through each record absolutely fine and then it just hangs at the end, after reaching the last row (which was processed correctly).

My code is below:

```
function importDataFromSAN() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  data.shift();

  const formSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MyID');
  const formData = formSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  formData.shift();

  data.forEach(row => {

    const fileURL = row[41];
    const studentNumber = row[10];

    if (fileURL === '') {

      console.log('No form');

    }
    else {
      const file = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(fileURL);

      const medConditions = file.getRange('B49');
      const currentSituation = file.getRange('B54');

      const matchNumber = formData.filter(a => a[4] === studentNumber);

      matchNumber.forEach(a => {

        const healthNeeds = a[10];
        const learningDifficulty = a[18];
        const riskAssessment = a[27] + ' ' + a[29] + ' ' + a[31] + ' ' + a[33] + ' ' + a[35] + ' ' + a[37] + ' ' + a[39] + ' ' + a[41] + ' ' + a[43] + ' ' + a[45] + ' ' + a[47] + ' ' + a[49];
        const outsideAgencies = a[73] + ' ' + a[75] + ' ' + a[77] + ' ' + a[79] + ' ' + a[81];

        medConditions.setValue('Health Needs - ' + healthNeeds + '\nLearning Difficulties - ' + learningDifficulty);
        currentSituation.setValue('Risk Assessment Details - ' + riskAssessment + '\nOutside Agencies Details - ' + outsideAgencies);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I tired running the script manually. I was expecting it to fail after hitting a certain number but it made it through all rows and then got hung up at the very end.

EDIT: After a long wait, it completed on the manual run. I do run a different script from a different project at the same time as this one, could that cause the issue, or is the limit per project and other projects have no impact?

Comment: Are you running any scripts as custom functions?

Comment: Take a look to the execution logs to check how many simultaneos executions are ocurring and to the triggers page to verify that only one trigger exists for your script. If  you need further help please add more details like describing how the trigger is created, the type of trigger used, if your spreadsheet is shared and is such case how it's used.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me. I don't have any custom functions. This is simply being run from a Day Trigger set between 2am and 3am every day. I would have assumed that there would be no simultaneous executions, since it is only being triggered once a day. Also, in the logs, the time it took to run to the error was no longer than the next trigger, from 3am to 4am, which did complete without failure. The strange thing is, it seems to have processed to the last row of the spreadsheet again before failing, so it is almost like it didn't fail but then got hung up trying to end the process.

Comment: I just ran it again manually and it got hung up at the end but completed without failure. The strange thing is, this is the only script I, personally, have running from any of my projects at 2am to 3am. I am literally only running that single script (where the code is above) and it seems to work manually (albeit with a long hang up before completing) but not from the single trigger.

Comment: The manual run took 414.1 seconds without failure, whereas the one that did fail only took 327.533 seconds before it decided to fail. I just don't understand why it would fail after completing every row and after less time than the manual run which did work. Thanks for looking into this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to stop the error from happening. I made a new column in my spreadsheet to check if the data had been transferred or not and spliced a 'Yes' if it had. Then I had to run it once manually, which it luckily didn't fail on.

Now, a new if/else checks if the new column has a 'Yes' in it and will skip it if it does.

I then decided to add another column to check if the data coming in was different to the data in the spreadsheet, so I spliced the data to this new column of the data I was copying as a string and checked it against a string of the new data.

This means that all of the checking is done in the server before it opens any spreadsheets and the majority of the time it doesn't open any spreadsheets at all, as none of the data has changed.

This now runs really quickly and no longer errors.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the error `Exception: Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets` is caused when there are too many requests made to the Spreadsheet in a short period of time, this can be caused by not only how many times the script was triggered but also by the amount of time a request to the spreadsheet was made. This message is similar to other exception messages that are [documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages). Rather than being an issue with the project is an issue with the amount of times that you are accessing the specific spreadsheet.

In your case, the best way to solve the problem would be to analyze how you can reduce the workload put on the spreadsheet since you are using a trigger, as this means that the function will run each time the event from the trigger is met.

Comment: I'm not sure I am accessing the sheet too many times. I access 2 sheets once each to import the data and then I access lots of different sheets where I write data. So each sheet in the process is only accessed and written to and from once, even though a lot of sheets are being accessed. Could it be the accessing of lots of sheets that is the problem? I can't see that this would be much more different from scripts where a lot of single emails are sent, but the sheet is only accessed once to retrieve the data and once to write the updated data back, which is what I try to do with all my scripts.